# Pagination doesn't get data on second page from isset method

Tags: php, pagination

I'm showing some images from database. On first I showing all images and then if user click on button I want filter it with query.

```
  <div class="align_center  gallery">

              <?php
               include "anj.php";
              if($_GET['submit']){
                    $sql =  'SELECT * FROM new_photos WHERE weight BETWEEN 10 AND 15';
             anjaan($sql);
             }
             else{
                    $sql='select * from new_photos';
            anjaan($sql); }
              ?>
                </div>
                 <div class="  align_center ">
               <div class=" col-md-12 pagination gallery">
              <?php    
                echo $paginationctrl;
                ?>
                </div>
              </div>
```

when i click on button

```
                  <form method="GET" >
                     <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                    </form>
```

then it show images and page from first query (if statement)

```
 "'SELECT * FROM new_photos WHERE weight BETWEEN 10 AND 15';"
```

it shows exact page that this query has, but when I click on 2nd page it show content from else statement

```
 "'SELECT * FROM new_photos ";
```

I want that when I click on 2nd page after I clicked submit button it should show images from first query.

Pagination code is

```
global $paginationctrl;
 $paginationctrl='';
 if($last !=1){

     if($pagenum>1){
              $previous = $pagenum-1;
              $paginationctrl .='<a  href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Pr</a>'.'&nbsp;';
              for($i = $pagenum-3 ;$i<$pagenum;$i++){
                       if($i>0){
                                $paginationctrl .='<a  class="active" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>'.'&nbsp;';
                       }
              }
     }

  $paginationctrl .=''.$pagenum.'&nbsp;'  ;
      for($i = $pagenum+1 ;$i<$last;$i++){
               $paginationctrl .='<a  class="active" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>'.'&nbsp;';
                       if($i>=$pagenum+4){
                               break;
                       }
              }
     if($pagenum != $last){
              $next =$pagenum+1;
             $paginationctrl .=' <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a>';
     }
    }
```

Comment: fisrt of all - why are you using form ? use just link instead. You have to provide to php somehow that you want results from page 2. So `<a href="file.php?page=1">1</a><a href="file.php?page=2">2</a>` and in php read `$_GET['page']` and serve data depend in it

Comment: there is 2 different query , i want that if user dont want to sort images than else statement get in use. and if user want to sort images than only sorted image should show

Comment: in page 2 link do `<a href="file.php'.(isset($_GET['submit'])?'?submit=submit':'').'">` which is not right way to do it but it works..

Comment: check pagination code

Comment: i think problem is with isset method . can i have an alternative for it .

Comment: if you want to check if array has set key you have to use isset like: `if(isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit']){`

Comment: problem is that the state when you press button do not persist, you need to do save that state somehow... look at this adress: `/?pn=2&submit=submit` this is what you want right ?

Comment: it's still showing from second queryy . i want that if user click on submit button if statement should set for webpage until other button pressed .

Comment: how to permanent set query if sumbit button has clicked

Comment: how i do that and i dont want to change pagintion code cause there are many button and querys

Comment: use sessions/cookies

Comment: and how i learn about it ,please provide any link

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: will it help ? ..

Comment: can you help me individualy ?

Comment: yea mmt i will post example

Comment: please tell me how to store this session so it will show images from first query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

session_start(); // this have to be called before any output

if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    $_SESSION['sort'] = $_GET['sort'] == 'true';
}

if(isset($_SESSION['sort']) && $_SESSION['sort']){
    echo 'sorted<br />';
}else{
    echo 'unsorted<br />';
}

?>

<!-- link get method -->
<a href="?sort=true">sorted</a><br />
<a href="?sort=false">unsorted</a>

<!-- form get method -->
<form method="GET">
<select name="sort">
  <option value="true">sorted</option>
  <option value="false">unsorted</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

in your code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    $_SESSION['sort'] = $_GET['sort'] == 'true';
}

include "anj.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['sort']) && $_SESSION['sort']){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM new_photos WHERE weight BETWEEN 10 AND 15';
    anjaan($sql);
} else {
    $sql = 'select * from new_photos';
    anjaan($sql);
}
?>
```

choose links or form from above and don't forget to put `session_start();` to very top of your file